# custom hook callback only has access to it's initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a custom hook within my **React** app that passes down a couple of functions to to the `Component` which the hook is attached to. These functions are used to update media based on whether or not the hook considers itself `mounted`.

However, I've come across a problem where when I return a function (`play`) from my hook and then call that function, it updates the data based on the initial state of the hook (despite the state having been updated many times).

```
const usePlayer = () => {
    const audioRef = useRef(__GLOBAL_AUDIO);
    const [state, setState] = useReducer((state, newState) => ({...state, ...newState}), {
        mounted: false,
        playing: false,
    });

    const play = () => ensureMounted(() => { 
        audioRef.current.play(); 
    });
    const ensureMounted = callback => {
        // This if statement will never run as this function does not 
        // seem to get any state other than the initially supplied one
        if(state.mounted){
            callback();
            return;
        }

        // ensureMounted will always skip to this portion of the function
        // despite what the current state is
        audioRef.current.src = cdn("/link/to/new/src.mp3");
        onLoad(callback);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // This function is tied to redux, but is irrelevant. Just know 
        // that mounted does change from true to false and vice-versa - often.
        const _mounted = checkToSeeIfMounted();
        setState({ mounted: _mounted });
    }, deps);

    return {
        playing: state.playing,
        play: play,
    };
};
```

Now obviously this code has been **extremely** simplified, but I hope it still conveys the problem that I'm facing. I have a hunch that the problem lies within the fact that **React** might be passing down an old(?) reference to the function on each re-render, but I'm unsure and the official docs are so vague about the "advanced" functions that I'm not sure how to use them or if they'd even be useful.

All help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @Viet I feel as though I've been as clear as I can be with what my problem is.

Comment: I also don't think so. What do you _think_ should happen that isn't? Why do you think that should happen and not what does? Also why did you completely change this question - it had a working example and you got rid of it.

Comment: @Jamiec I _think_ what should happen is when the state is updated (ie. when `mounted` is updated), the function should act accordingly when called by a component. The problem is, let's assume we call `ensureMounted` multiple times from a component over it's lifespan, the original state will have changed - and yet `ensureMounted` will **still** only act based upon the initial state.

Comment: @Jamiec I updated it to be more clear and concise. I feel as though the original was too dulled down to make sense (I like to make questions as simple as possible since StackOverflow users seem to shy away from anything longer than a few lines of code).

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be working as expected. There are no **apparent** issues with references. (***EDIT: At least in your original question's code***).

Remember that a custom `hook` works at the 'same level' of the component where it is used. In other words, it is the same as if you were using the custom hook's `useState` directly in your component. Actions making your custom hook 're-render' will cause your component to re-render as well.

Remember that state changes usually take place asynchronously. This can result in a confusing behavior sometimes.

When your code runs for the first time, both `useEffect` hooks run in order. The first `useEffect` will run only once because it has no dependencies (the `hook.example` reference inside it will always be the first reference (eventually old), but it is run only once, so you will not have any issue unless you do some other things inside that callback (like adding event listeners or performing some async taks) or you call `hook.example` (thus changing original state) before the `useEffect` runs).

Continuing, after `hook.example` is called, the current value of data is logged (`false`), then a state update is requested (async), code execution continues and the second `useEffect` is fired, logging the current value (`false`). Finally, state is updated and your custom hook 're-renders' causing your component to re-render too. Now, first `useEffect` does not fire and second `useEffect` fires because `hook.data` changed. Finally, the new data value is logged (`true`).

When calling `hook.example` by clicking the button there are no problems because `hook.example` is always holding the latest reference there.

Please also note that good practice requires your first `useEffect` hook to have `hook` as a dependency (then eventual filtering logic should be performed inside the `useEffect` callback) and in your case, adding `hook` to the dependencies array would cause an infinite loop. Maybe your actual code is different, but it is good to know that.

If you need additional clarification, do not hesitate to comment.

```js
const useHook = () => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(false);

    const example = () =>
        preCallCheck(() => {
            setData(!data);
        });

    const preCallCheck = (callback) => {
        console.log('preCallCheck()\t', data);
        callback();
    };

    return {
        data: data,
        example: example
    };
};

const Parent = () => {
    const hook = useHook();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        hook.example();
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect()\t', hook.data);
    }, [hook.data]);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{'Hello, World!'}</h1>
        <button type={'button'} onClick={() => hook.example()}>{'Click Me'}</button>
      </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @GROVER. I saw your new posted code and I think that your problem is most likely were you use your custom hook, not in the hook itself which seems to be ok. Are you sure that your `mounted` state is being eventually set to true?

Comment: Absolutely certain. When I log  `_mounted` in my `useEffect` it will return both `true` and `false` depending on conditions.

Comment: @GROVER. and if do `console.log(state.mounted)` right before your `return` statement inside your hook, do you always get your intended value? If so, the problem is with the hook usage.

Comment: I've run into the same problem and after a long search, I just had forgotten to pass down the hook callbacks as dependencies to the useEffect inside the `Component` to which the hook is attached to. I tried to print the state right before the return statement inside the hook and I got the expected output, that was my clue.